# List element fetching

Tags: erlang

In Erlang, I would like to fetch the x-nth element of a list that contains n elements. I could use `lists:nth/2` but this one throws an error when x>n and I would like to get a default value (`[]` in this case) instead.

Is there a built-in way to do this without having to check the length of the list?

Comment: I suggest building your own function that implements this behaviour.

Comment: Unfortunately not, there is BIF or NIF that might do this for you. Your best bet is to write a small wrapper function with a guard to check for the length.

Comment: As far as I could research, looks like @matov is right here. Could you post it as an answer so I can close this?

Comment: @AsierAzkuenaga thanks, posted my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately not, there isn't a BIF or NIF that might do this for you. Your best bet is to write a small wrapper function with a guard to check for the length. Something like:

```
F = fun (N, L) when N > length(L) -> [];
        (N, L) -> lists:nth(N,L) end.
```

Comment: My only concern with using `length(L)` in the guard is that `length` has to traverse the entire list in order to determine the length. This can take some time if the list is long even if all you want is the first element. For example, `Short = lists:seq(1, 10).` and `Long = lists:seq(1,10000000).` on my laptop I have the following  `timer:tc(erlang, length, [Short]). => {4,10}` versus `timer:tc(erlang, length, [Long]).  => {17085,10000000}`

Answer (score 1):

```
1> N = fun(Pos,List) ->
1>     try                 
1>         {ok,lists:nth(Pos,List)}
1>     catch                   
1>         _:_ -> {error,[]}       
1>     end                     
1> end.
#Fun<erl_eval.12.52032458>
2> N(2,[1,2,3,4]).         
{ok,2}
3> N(5,[1,2,3,4]).         
{error,[]}
4>
```

I use tagged return values to make the difference between `{ok,[]} = N(2,[a,[],b]).` and `{error,[]} = N(500,[a]).`